# Link from a formula to an external website

Tags: salesforce1-app, ios

I'm implementing a field through a text formula inside my salesforce layout:

```
HYPERLINK($Setup.Endpoints__c.Server_Url__c + "/pdf/" +  field__c ,"Open Last Pdf")
```

This link works correctly when clicked on a normal browser as it redirects to an external website.
The problem is that when opening through Salesforce1 app on iOs, it doesn't open a new window or a browser, but says: 
`Navigation started when state=1`

Comment: It looks like a bug in Salesforce1 App itself. Please check if it is updated one. We generally see these error because of hybrid app component. Someone may have workaround.